# How do I reverse engineer an Electron compiled file?- a JSC Bytenode file

Tags: ghidra, deobfuscation, decompile, unknown-data

I have a [bytenode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytenode) JSC file - which is described as:

> This tool truly compiles your JavaScript code into V8 bytecode, so
> that you can protect your source code. It can be used with Node.js, as
> well as Electron and NW.js (check examples/ directory).

It obfuscates your Electron app. How do I go about decompiling it? x64dbg/Ollydbg won't recognize the file. Is it possible?

There used to be a Ghidra plugin for this called `ghidra_nodejs` but it has been removed from Github ([Wayback machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220102202434/https://github.com/PositiveTechnologies/ghidra_nodejs)).

Comment: PositiveTechnologies {the owner of that github repo) has an excellent article about this subject.   
https://swarm.ptsecurity.com/how-we-bypassed-bytenode-and-decompiled-node-js-bytecode-in-ghidra/

Comment: @user22363 I saw that before but it doesn’t help since the Ghidra plugin doesn’t exist anymore. Thanks

Comment: You can find the plugin at Natalya Tlyapova's github [1], she co-authored that blog and work as Security Researcher at Positive Technologies.     
Positive Technologies is one of these Russian companies that the US sanctioned, that why their GitHub account was removed.   

[1]https://github.com/ntlyapova/ghidra_nodejs

Comment: @user22363 thanks! Have you installed the plugin before? I'm having trouble with building the plugin (step 4 of the readme file). Would you be able to build the plugin and send me the Zip file? And I'll reward the bounty

Comment: No, I didn't use it before. I tried to compile it multiple times but apparently it refuse to work properly, I even compiled Ghidra from the source following Ghidra's DevGuide and eclipse still throw errors left and right.

Comment: @user22363 got it. Thanks for trying